# UI not updated when using SavedStateHandle

Tags: java, android, lifecycle

Following android's architecture [guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide), I am experimenting with `SavedStateHandle` in my view model. So when I post any changes from a thread to the view model, it doesn't reflect on UI. However, without SavedStateHandle the UI changes reflect just fine.

```java
public class UserViewModel extends ViewModel {
    UserRepository userRepository;
    private static final String USER_KEY = "user_key";

    private SavedStateHandle mState;

    public UserViewModel(SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle) {
        mState = savedStateHandle;
        this.userRepository = new UserRepository();
    }



    public LiveData<String> getUserId() {
        return mState.getLiveData(USER_KEY, userRepository.getUserId());
    }

    public void setUserId(String value) {
        mState.set(USER_KEY, value);
    }

}
```

```java
public class UserFragment extends Fragment {

    private UserViewModel mViewModel;

    public static UserFragment newInstance() {
        return new UserFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull @NotNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(UserViewModel.class);
        mViewModel.getUserId().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), s -> {
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_1)).setText(s);
        });
        Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mViewModel.setUserId("111111");
        });
    }

    public UserViewModel getmViewModel() {
        return mViewModel;
    }
}
```

Main Activity

- my view only has one `framelayout` with id `sample_fragment`

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private UserViewModel userViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            UserFragment userFragment = new UserFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.sample_fragment, userFragment);
            transaction.commit();
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                userViewModel.setUserId("1");
            });
        }


    }
}
```

with this code, the changes don't reflect on UI. however when I replace the `SaveStateHandle` with `MutableLiveData` then a simple `postValue` changes the screen just fine. From what I have read, it seems the live data is changed only when the lifecycle is in some specific states (like `CREATED`).

Answer (score 0):

You set a default value in your getUserId, but I don't see where you use postValue on the data in SavedStateHandle.

I would add a `mUserId` member and move the code in getUserId to the ViewModel constructor to make sure it's initialized before any write to it. Then make set and post methods:

```
LiveData<String> mUserId;

public UserViewModel(SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle) {
    mState = savedStateHandle;
    this.userRepository = new UserRepository();
    mUserId = mState.getLiveData(USER_KEY, userRepository.getUserId());
}


public LiveData<String> getUserId() {
    return mUserId;
}

public void setUserId(String value) {
    mState.getLiveData(USER_KEY).setValue(value);
}

public void postUserId(String value) {
    mState.getLiveData(USER_KEY).postValue(value);
}
```